# DrawRect, DrawOval, DrawLine, FillRect and FillOval only draw a straight horizontal line in code provided

Tags: java, user-interface

I am currently practising GUI in Java and have made a program that procedurally generates random shapes depending on the user input. However, it seems to not be working correctly.
The program currently looks like this (Lines instead of Rectangles and Ovals): 
[image: Lines instead of Rectangles and Ovals]

However, as suggested above the program should have some filled, some unfilled rectangles and ovals and lines. These horizontal lines are not representative of what the output should look like.

This is the code below.

DrawPanelTest.java (main file)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class DrawPanelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many shapes should exist?");
        int intAmount = Integer.parseInt(amount);
        DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel(intAmount);
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Lines: " + drawPanel.getLineAmount() + ", Ovals: " + drawPanel.getOvalAmount()
                + ", Rectangles: " + drawPanel.getRectangleAmount());
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        jFrame.add(drawPanel);
        jFrame.add(text, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jFrame.setSize(600, 600);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

DrawPanel.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private Random random = new Random();
    private Shape[] shapes;
    private int lineAmount;
    private int ovalAmount;
    private int rectangleAmount;

    public DrawPanel(int amount) {
        shapes = new Shape[amount];
        for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
            Color color = new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
            int choice = random.nextInt(3);
            switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                shapes[i] = new Line(random.nextInt(300), random.nextInt(300), random.nextInt(300), random.nextInt(300),
                        color);
                lineAmount++;
                break;
            case 1:
                shapes[i] = new Oval(random.nextInt(300), random.nextInt(300), random.nextInt(300), random.nextInt(300),
                        color, random.nextBoolean());
                ovalAmount++;
                break;
            case 2:
                shapes[i] = new Rectangle(random.nextInt(300), random.nextInt(300), random.nextInt(300),
                        random.nextInt(300), color, random.nextBoolean());
                rectangleAmount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getLineAmount() {
        return lineAmount;
    }

    public int getOvalAmount() {
        return ovalAmount;
    }

    public int getRectangleAmount() {
        return rectangleAmount;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            shape.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Shape.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class Shape {
    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;
    private Color color;

    public Shape() {
        setX1(0);
        setY1(0);
        setX2(100);
        setY2(100);
        setColor(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Shape(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
        setX1(x1);
        setY1(y1);
        setX2(x2);
        setY2(y1);
        setColor(color);
    }

    public void setX1(int newX1) {
        if (newX1 >= 0) {
            x1 = newX1;
        } else {
            x1 = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getX1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public void setY1(int newY1) {
        if (newY1 >= 0) {
            y1 = newY1;
        } else {
            y1 = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getY1() {
        return y1;
    }

    public void setX2(int newX2) {
        if (newX2 >= 0) {
            x2 = newX2;
        } else {
            x2 = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getX2() {
        return x2;
    }

    public void setY2(int newY2) {
        if (newY2 >= 0) {
            y2 = newY2;
        } else {
            y2 = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getY2() {
        return y2;
    }

    public void setColor(int r, int g, int b) {
        color = new Color(r, g, b);
    }

    public void setColor(Color newColor) {
        color = newColor;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
}
```

BoundedShape.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.math.*;

public abstract class BoundedShape extends Shape {
    private boolean filled;

    public BoundedShape() {
        super();
        setFill(false);
    }

    public BoundedShape(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color, boolean fill) {
        super(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
        setFill(fill);
    }

    public void setFill(boolean fill) {
        if (fill == true || fill == false) {
            filled = fill;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fill has to be either true or false");
        }
    }

    public boolean getFill() {
        return filled;
    }

    public int getUpperLeftX() {
        return Math.min(super.getX1(), super.getX2());
    }

    public int getUpperLeftY() {
        return Math.min(super.getY1(), super.getY2());
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return Math.abs(super.getX2() - super.getX1());
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return Math.abs(super.getY2() - super.getY1());
    }
}
```

Line.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Line extends Shape {

    public Line() {
        super();
    }

    public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
        super(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(super.getColor());
        g.drawLine(super.getX1(), super.getY1(), super.getX2(), super.getY2());
    }
}
```

Rectangle.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Rectangle extends BoundedShape {
    public Rectangle() {
        super();
    }

    public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color, boolean filled) {
        super(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, filled);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(super.getColor());
        if (super.getFill() == false) {
            g.drawRect(super.getUpperLeftX(), super.getUpperLeftY(), super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
        } else if (super.getFill() == true) {
            g.fillRect(super.getUpperLeftX(), super.getUpperLeftY(), super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Oval.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Oval extends BoundedShape {
    public Oval() {
        super();
    }

    public Oval(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color, boolean filled) {
        super(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, filled);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(super.getColor());
        if (super.getFill() == false) {
            g.drawOval(super.getUpperLeftX(), super.getUpperLeftY(), super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
        } else if (super.getFill() == true) {
            g.fillOval(super.getUpperLeftX(), super.getUpperLeftY(), super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
mabdi36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `draw()` method of `Oval` and `Rectangle`, you call `super.getWidth()` and `super.getHeight()`. But your height is always 0, because of a typo within your constructor in `Shape`:

**You call `setY2()` and pass in `y1`, so `y2 == y1`, thus `abs(y2 - y1) = 0`**.

```java
 public Shape(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
        setX1(x1);
        setY1(y1);
        setX2(x2);
        setY2(y1); // change this to setY2(y2)
        setColor(color);
    }
```

Now height won't be 0 and you'll see your shape in 2D.